# error on int.Parse()

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
 int a = 50;
 float b = 50.60f;

 a = int.Parse(b.ToString());
```

On run time this parsing gives as error. Why it is please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: a float is not an int. Furthermore, this code doesn't make much sense. If you want to get rid of the decimals, use `a = (int)b`.

Comment: Can you explain What you are trying it to achieve here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [int.Parse throws NumberFormatException if the string does not contain a parsable integer;](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) `50.6` is not a prasable integer.

Answer (score 5):

It's trying to parse the string "50.6" - that can't be parsed as an integer, because 50.6 *isn't* an integer. From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx):

> The s parameter contains a number of the form:
>
> ```
> [ws][sign]digits[ws]
> ```

Perhaps you want to parse it back as a float and then *cast* to an integer?

```
a = (int) float.Parse(b.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to parse a string that does not represent an integer into an integer.

This is why you are getting an exception.

Answer (score 2):

It gives an error because you are trying to parse as int a string representing a float.

```
float b = 50.60f; // b = 50.6
                  // b.ToString() = "50.6" or "50,6" depending on locale
                  // int.Parse("50.6") MUST give an error because "50.6" is
                  // not a string representation of an integer
```

What is it that you want to do? Convert a float to an int? Just do this:

```
float b = 50.6f;
int a = (int)b;
```

That will truncate the value of b to simply **50**.

Or do you want it rounded off to the nearest integer?

```
int a = (int)Math.Round(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the error message not specific enough?

> Input string was not in a correct format.

`int.Parse` must take a string which can be parsed to an integer. The string "50.6" does not fulfil that requirement!